# Using If and Switch statements together in a program

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

I am a student and I am trying to make a very simple program that displays the quadrant of an angle that is entered in by the user.

However I want it to display that the angle is on the X axis or Y axis if the user enters the angle as 0,90,180 or 270.

I did put these 4 conditions in an if statement but the code is not terminating there and I am also getting the quadrant number corresponding to that angle. How do I terminate the code for those 4 angles after the if statement?

```
#include <iostream.h>
void main()

{
int angle;

cout<<"Enter an angle: ";
cin>>angle;

if (angle==90) cout<<"The angle lies on the positive Y axis";
else if (angle==0) cout<<"The angle lies on the positive X axis";
else if (angle==180) cout<<"The angle lies on the negative X axis";
else if (angle==270) cout<<"The angle lies on the negative Y axis";


angle=(angle/90)+1;

switch(angle)
{
case 1: cout<<"First Quadrant"; break;
case 2: cout<<"Second Quadrant"; break;
case 3: cout<<"Third Quadrant"; break;
case 4: cout<<"Fourth Quadrant"; break;
default: cout<<"That is not a valid angle.";

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify a little like this for example:

```
int quadrant=(angle/90)+1;

if (angle==90) cout<<"The angle lies on the positive Y axis";
else if (angle==0) cout<<"The angle lies on the positive X axis";
else if (angle==180) cout<<"The angle lies on the negative X axis";
else if (angle==270) cout<<"The angle lies on the negative Y axis";
else
switch(quadrant)
{
    case 1: cout<<"First Quadrant"; break;
    case 2: cout<<"Second Quadrant"; break;
    case 3: cout<<"Third Quadrant"; break;
    case 4: cout<<"Fourth Quadrant"; break;
    default: cout<<"That is not a valid angle.";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Alex can solve your problem.

In addition to it, I think you may consider changing the type of object angle from int to double and adding more logic to handle the negative and none integer values.

Comment: Don't! You must implement double equality checks, and that is way beyond the scope of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a separate function that has early return:

```
string angleDescription(int angle)
{
    if (angle <  0) return "Invalid input";
    if (angle == 0) return "Positive X axis"
    if (angle < 90) return "First quadrant";

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (angle%90==0)
{
    switch(angle/90)
    {
        case 0: cout << "Angle lies on +X axis";    break;
        case 1: cout << "Angle lies on +Y axis";    break;
        case 2: cout << "Angle lies on -X axis";    break;
        case 3: cout << "Angle lies on -Y axis";    break;
    }
}

else
{
    switch(angle/90)
    {
        case 0:  cout << "First Quadrant";  break;
        case 1:  cout << "Second Quadrant"; break;
        case 2:  cout << "Third Quadrant";  break;
        case 3:  cout << "Fourth Quadrant"; break;
        default: cout << "Invalid angle";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what the problem was and what your suggestion does to solve it? :)

Comment: My suggestion provides a solution to the problem proposed (How do I terminate the code for those 4 angles after the if statement?)